# Making an RxJava Operator Chain Concurrent

Tags: java, asynchronous, reactive-programming, rx-java

I've just started using RxJava. I've been attempting to build a data pipeline that downloads large amount of data from different sources and inserts the data into a database in a concurrent way.

My basic pipeline form looks like the following:

```
        Observable.range(1, 5)
            .concatMap((i) -> {
                return Observable.range(i, 2);
            })
            .concatMap((i) -> {
                return Observable.range(i, 2);
            })
            .subscribe((i) -> { System.out.println(i); }, System.out::println,() -> { System.out.println("Complete"); });
```

Whenever I call observeOn instead of running and printing out all the numbers that the above printed out, instead nothing prints out. Why is this? I would expect that the next concatMap, and subscribe would just use the computation scheduler as well. Code is posted below.

```
        Observable.range(1, 5)
            .concatMap((i) -> {
                return Observable.range(i, 2);
            })
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .concatMap((i) -> {
                return Observable.range(i, 2);
            })
            .subscribe((i) -> { System.out.println(i); }, System.out::println,() -> { System.out.println("Complete"); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guess since you did not supply context, but you have to block if you're changing threads since the main is not blocked and you're possibly terminating before the other scheduler had a chance to run:

```
Observable.range(1, 5)
        .concatMap((i) -> {
            return Observable.range(i, 2);
        })
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .concatMap((i) -> {
            return Observable.range(i, 2);
        })
        .subscribe((i) -> { System.out.println(i); }, System.out::println,() -> { System.out.println("Complete"); });
// block to let other schedulers finish
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Comment: Yes this ended up being the problem. Is there any scheduler that will schedule operators on the main thread the code is called from? I looked through the documentation and didn't see anything that looked like what I needed.

Comment: Try `Schedulers.immediate()` or use `Observable.toBlocking()`.

Comment: Tried immediate, didn't work. I am essentially trying to make the above code wait until the observers are all complete without the arbitrary sleep. I'm thinking that maybe creating a ThreadPool, passing it into the Executor interface, and then waiting for the ThreadPool to finish might be possible.

Comment: Still missing context here. This is an x-y problem. If you're waiting for multiple observables maybe you should `Observable.merge()` them and wait for them to complete by blocking? Maybe use a `CountDownLatch` to block the main thread and `Observable.doOnComplete()` to count it down from the observables? Many strategies can be used here depending on the context.

Comment: The context is that I have to make one call to a web service that returns a list of identifiers; then using those identifiers I want to concurrently request the information about all those identifiers. That's what the two concatMaps are for. `Observable.merge()` doesn't make much sense to me because I must get the first list of identifiers to be able to query for information about them. `Observable.doOnComplete()` looks interesting, but I'm still not sure how I would signal within a function to the main thread that everything is done now.

Comment: You would count it down when everything completes (`Observable...doOnComplete( () -> countDownLatch.countDown())`) and the main thread will `await(...)` on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Reut!

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments to get more context, I'm assuming you want to make a request to get a list of ids (items summary), then make one additional request per returned id to get each item's detail, and then do something with the results (the items).

Considering you already have methods to build and fire requests, returning an `Observable`. You can wrap the http related code and defer an Observable out of it, or create an Observable from a `Future`, in case your http library returns `Future`s.

```
// you have this available
Observable<Summary> = querySummary(summaryId);
Observable<Item> = queryItem(itemId);
```

I didn't run any of the following code, so take it as a guidance. You could start with:

```
Observable<Item> itemsObservable = querySummary(summaryId)
    .flatMap(summary -> {
        return Observable.from(summary.getItemsIdsList());
    })
    .map(itemId -> {
        return queryItem(itemId);
    });
```

You are querying the Summary, then using the `flatMap` operator to emit individual returned ids. Then you can `map` each id to a request. At the end you could subscribe to `itemsObservable` to let the individual `Item` objects flow.

If you want to save the Items in the database, before subscribing, you could plug an `doOnNext` at the tail of the last `map` and save each Item. If you want to sum a value from each Item, or do any aggregation, you can use `reduce`. And so on.. Following the way it is, with a single `.subscribe()` at the end, this code runs all in the main thread (in case your http library doesn't have any fancy thread pool feature).

```
itemsObservable.doOnNext(item -> {
    // do something in whatever thread it might be running
}).subscribe();
```

If you want to fire the summary request and wait for it asynchronously, then fire the items' requests also concurrently as new item ids are arriving, you can add `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())` as you did.

```
Observable<Item> itemsObservable = querySummary(summaryId)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) // from here, continue in the background
    .flatMap(summary -> { // ...
```

Notice that you are telling the Observable chain to follow the execution in another thread and forgetting about it. In same cases, this is just what you want. But if you are running this from a plain `public static void main()` method as your program body, your program will shutdown before the end of the background execution, and that's expected. If you were dealing directly with references to thread objects, you should be responsible to `join()` the threads by your own, making the main program wait for them.

Since reactive streams are meant to hide the threading complexity, you just need to "say" you want to get all together at the end of the party. In this case, to bring the execution back to the main thread, you can plug a `.toBlocking()` or `.toList()`. Then you can safely get the results at the `onNext` of your subscription in your current thread.

```
itemsObservable
    .toBlocking()
    .subscribe(item -> {
        // blocking the main thread
        // do something on each item 
});
```

or..

```
itemsObservable
    .toList()
    .subscribe(itemsList -> {
        // blocking the main thread
        // do something with the whole list at once
});
```

There are lots of different ways you can compose Observables, creating one or more streams, merging them, running them asynchronously or not. So, it's up to your needs.

I hope it helps!